# Is there a jQuery solution to load a document string into an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm looking to load a webpage into an iframe via a string output from PHP. Every example I've seen showing this is Javascript based.

Curious is there is a jQuery method to accomplish loading a string as the content for an iframe?

This is the Javscript (partial jQuery) implementation I'm currently using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        setTimeout( function() {
            var resume = document.getElementById('resume_holder')
            var doc = resume.contentWindow.document;
            var $body = $('body',doc);

            var htmlString = "<h1>TEST</h1>";
            $body.html(htmlString);
        }, 1 );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript. You can just rewrite the JS solution using the jQuery APIs.

Comment: Usually that's the case, but I'm not sure here because of the iFrame. You can see the example I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var htmlString = "<h1>TEST</h1>";
    $('#resume_holder').contents().find('body').html(htmlString);
});
```

- [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) instead of `.contentWindow.document` / `.contentDocument`.
  `.contents()`, called on a frame element, returns the document, wrapped in a jQuery object.
- `$(doc).find('body')` is a faster equivalent to `$('body', doc)`.

Comment: Thanks. That works great. I had the same thing before, except without 'find('body')' -- I'm a bit confused as to how that works here?

Comment: No your answer is perfect. Originally I was confused because there was no <body> tag in the iframe, so I didn't think to use $find('body') -- now I get it. Thanks again.

Comment: @jsuissa A fully-loaded (generated) HTML document **always** contains a `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags. In JavaScript, they can be accessed using [`document.documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.documentElement), [`document.head`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.head) and [`document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.body). `document.head` is relatively new. So, if you're concerned about browser support, use `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]`.